# Return one record from a form data source

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a form with an existing data source. This data source has a one to many relationship to another table that is **not** an existing data source. Even though this second table contains multiple records (one to many), the field in the table that I want is duplicated across all records. Therefore I want to add this second table as a data source, but only return one record from it.

If I add the second table directly, than my form contains a line for each record instead of just one.

Comment: 1:M relations are usually handled through a grid control. If you want 1 record from M records, then you've to specify a condition based on what we'd select that particular record.

Comment: There isn't anything to filter on. The 1:M link works for other situations just not this one. I just want to return 1 record from the joined data source and not all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was solved by creating a view to use as the new datasource. This view defined a calculated column that was based on a method that contained a query string that used TOP 1. The details in much more detail are at Martin Dráb's blog: https://community.dynamics.com/ax/b/goshoom/archive/2015/06/29/join-first-line-in-ax-2012.

Answer (score 1):

Use the property LinkType=ExistJoin on the datasource for your second table.

See the TransactionLog form for example.

Comment: OP most likely wants to use the data of the joined table ("the field in the table that I want" and "only return one record from it"), which would not be available with an `exists join`.

Comment: Correct. I want to use the field that is the same across all records.